# Authentication between PHP client and .Net server

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

I intent on creating a PHP application that regularly calls into an ASP.Net website to check for updates and then make another call to download updates).

- I will be using SSL for transport security.
- The clients need to be PHP as they run other bespoke bash commands.
- I will need to download data and I've not decided what form.

Can anyone please suggest for my .net application:

- How to restrict access to the server (I won't know incoming request IP's)?
- The best structured data transport mechanism? maybe I could use JSON?

nb. if I can create a web service that PHP could consume that's even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSON is definitively a good idea. It's less verbose than xml and fit particularly well with object oriented programming.

For your authentication issue, you could pass over each request an authentication token (a random string) that only your web service and your PHP code will know.
This is safe since SSL will encrypt the request and your auth token will never be "clear" on the network.